# Multiline text in navigation

Tags: website-design, navigation

Should points of a left-side navigation bar be single line with ellipsis or multiple lines?

I have a strong opinion that single lines are preferable, because eyes are reading first words/characters in every line, and second lines distract from this process.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your users will not want to navigate to the page just to find out what the title is.

If I saw "Practical En...", I would not know what that page is.

**I'd rather have more space dedicated to navigation so I could read the full titles.**

There are many patterns for navigation out there and can be found with some web searches, but they can vary greatly depending on your target device and platform.

Comment: Users already know the title, because it's their subscriptions. Short titles on image are made so that multiline effect is more pronounced. Titles are made by users and are out of our control, thus it's impossible to fit any title there. Previously there was no such navigation, and there is no way to impose restrictions on length of previously created titles.

Comment: You still need to reconsider ways to integrate the complete title. Making assumptions that the user knows what to expect from a cut out title could harm UX. There should be a way to integrate the complete title.